# PHP How To Turn Nested Foreach Into An Array of Arrays (Multidimensional Array)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arrayofarrays

I'm sorry because I'm probably not going to use the correct vocabulary here, but I'm trying to figure out "how-to" modify the following code so that it creates the array of arrays (Multidimensional Array). This code creates the structure illustrated in the image below, but I want it to create the array of arrays (Multidimensional Array) instead.

Basically, I want the 1001, 1002, 1004, etc... to be the main array. The nested arrays will be the strings that has the #1001, #1002, etc... in them. You'll notice the # in the string corresponds with number in the original array.

```
$combinedAssignmentData = []; 
foreach($assignmentsYES as $key=>$assignedIDs){
  $levels = array($assignedIDs);
    foreach($levels as $key=>$level){
      echo "<strong>$level</strong><br>";
      foreach($studentIDsubmissions as $k=>$individualSubmission){
        if (strpos($individualSubmission, $level) !== false) {
          echo "--$individualSubmission<br>";
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**var_export($assignmentsYES);**

```
array ( 0 => '1001', 1 => '1002', 2 => '1004', 3 => '1005', 4 => '1007', 5 => '1008', 6 => '1009', 7 => '1015', 8 => '1028', 9 => '1029', )
```

**var_export($studentIDsubmissions);**

```
array ( 0 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 1 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 2 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 3 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 4 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES', 5 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES', 6 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES', 7 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-About Me #1004|YES', 8 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Calendar #1007|YES', 9 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Wage Tracker #1008|YES', 10 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Stock Portfolio #1009|YES', 11 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Collaboration #1005|YES', 12 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Stock Portfolio #1009|YES', 13 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Collaboration #1005|YES', 14 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Dream Vacation Presentation #1015|YES', )
```

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Todd

Comment: It would be much easier if you had some sample data of this `$assignmentsYES` (use `var_export`, if you add any)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, thanks for helping! I've added the data.

Comment: I actually had it written before you posted the data ... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
$assignmentsYES = array ( 0 => '1001', 1 => '1002', 2 => '1004', 3 => '1005', 4 => '1007', 5 => '1008', 6 => '1009', 7 => '1015', 8 => '1028', 9 => '1029', );
$studentIDsubmissions = array ( 0 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 1 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 2 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 3 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 4 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES', 5 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES', 6 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES', 7 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-About Me #1004|YES', 8 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Calendar #1007|YES', 9 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Wage Tracker #1008|YES', 10 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Stock Portfolio #1009|YES', 11 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Collaboration #1005|YES', 12 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Stock Portfolio #1009|YES', 13 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Collaboration #1005|YES', 14 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Dream Vacation Presentation #1015|YES', );

$combinedAssignmentData = []; 
foreach($assignmentsYES as $key=>>$level){
        $combinedAssignmentData[$level] = 
                array_filter(
                    $studentIDsubmissions,
                    function($item)use($level){
                        return strpos($item, '#'.$level) !== false;
                    }
                );
}

print_r($combinedAssignmentData);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1001] => Array
        (
            [0] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO
            [1] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO
            [2] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO
            [3] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO
        )

    [1002] => Array
        (
            [4] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES
            [5] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES
            [6] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES
        )

    [1004] => Array
        (
            [7] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-About Me #1004|YES
        )

    [1005] => Array
        (
            [11] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Collaboration #1005|YES
            [13] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Collaboration #1005|YES
        )

    [1007] => Array
        (
            [8] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Calendar #1007|YES
        )

    [1008] => Array
        (
            [9] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Wage Tracker #1008|YES
        )

    [1009] => Array
        (
            [10] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Stock Portfolio #1009|YES
            [12] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Stock Portfolio #1009|YES
        )

    [1015] => Array
        (
            [14] => 346623@guhsd.net|TD-Dream Vacation Presentation #1015|YES
        )

    [1028] => Array
        (
        )

    [1029] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0784d9090a9cfbc0321cc0a5e2de68163f22e888)

***PS** 
I added a `#` in here `strpos($item, '#'.$level)`, which will improve the accuracy a bit.  It would be better to use a regular expression (in the array filter callback)

```
function($item)use($level){
   return preg_match('/#'.$level.'\|/', $item); //match `#{id}|`
}
```

Consider for example matching `1001` to id `10012` ~ strpos will just match the `1001` part with no regard.

If the oddly numbered keys for the sub array bug you you can wrap the `array_filter` in `array_values(array_filter(....));` to reset them.  Array filter retains the keys from the original array. In most cases the keys don't really matter, so I wouldn't worry about it unless you really have to.

## Update

After thinking about it and posting this

> be better to use a regular expression

Why don't we go with this one:

```
$assignmentsYES = array ( 0 => '1001', 1 => '1002', 2 => '1004', 3 => '1005', 4 => '1007', 5 => '1008', 6 => '1009', 7 => '1015', 8 => '1028', 9 => '1029', );
$studentIDsubmissions = array ( 0 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 1 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 2 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 3 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Share Test #1001|NO', 4 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES', 5 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES', 6 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-No Excuse Reflection #1002|YES', 7 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-About Me #1004|YES', 8 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Calendar #1007|YES', 9 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Wage Tracker #1008|YES', 10 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Stock Portfolio #1009|YES', 11 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Collaboration #1005|YES', 12 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Stock Portfolio #1009|YES', 13 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Collaboration #1005|YES', 14 => '346623@guhsd.net|TD-Dream Vacation Presentation #1015|YES', );

$combinedAssignmentData = []; 
foreach($assignmentsYES as $key=>$level){
    $combinedAssignmentData[$level] = preg_grep('/#'.$level.'\|/', $studentIDsubmissions);
}

print_r($combinedAssignmentData);
```

Using Preg Grep is a bit cleaner then array filter and a callback with a regular expression.  I also realized you had a superficial loop in there `$levels = array($assignedIDs);`  or basically `$levels = array($level);` or just `$level`.

Same output as before

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40d3df5c754ea0716352aa81227c1e8f7d5638aa)

Comment: thanks for your help with this! You solution worked, but I realized I need a slight change and I'm hoping you can help. Your solution created an "Associative Arrays", but I need it to be an "Indexed Array".  Can You please update your solution so it creates an "Indexed Array" in the same structure? Thanks again!

Comment: If you can show me an example (preferably as an update to the question) of what the expected output is, I can update it.  `it creates an "Indexed Array" in the same structure`  You can just do `array_values($combinedAssignmentData)` to remove the keys, or change this line `$combinedAssignmentData[$level] = preg_grep(...)` to `$combinedAssignmentData[] = preg_grep(...)`  That said the keys are very useful, and easy to work around.  For example want to know if there are items in a given ID `count($combinedAssignmentData[$id])`  - Think without the ID how will you find it....

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll work on this later today. Also, I appreciate extra insight you offer in your solutions and comments.  They really help someone learning the language and concepts better understand a solution.

Comment: Sure, glad I can help!